# JQuery not working on Bootstrap Carousel not displayed images

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-carousel

I'm struggling for hours on this problem. I'm using Bootstrap3 Carousel; what I would like to do is applying a CSS rule with JQuery (Note: the problem couldn't be solved with CSS-only solutions because the value I want to assign needs to be calculated with JQuery) on my **.toBottom** div.
1) This is the basic HTML structure of the carousel:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img />
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img />
    </div>

    <div class="item toBottom">
      <img />
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

2) The JQuery script basically calculates the new CSS "top" value for the **.toBottom** element. 
3) I noticed that, by default, the **.item** div that also has the **.active** class has

```
display: block;
```

and all the remaining "non-active" **.item** divs have

```
display: none;
```

The fact is that if I launch the JQuery script when .toBottom is **.active**, the CSS top value changes normally, *BUT* if I launch it when it is not .active (or it's **display:none**), **its CSS won't change at all**!

How can I solve this? I would like to apply the rule even if the .toBottom div is display:none.

Thank you in advance.
(I apologize if I wasn't too much clear, I tried to simplify the situation as much as possible)

**EDIT:**
This is the script:

```
var carouselHeight = $(".carousel-inner").outerHeight();
var newTop = carouselHeight - $(".item.toBottom > img").height();
if(newTop < 0)
  $(".item.toBottom > img").css("top", newTop);
else
  $(".item.toBottom > img").css("top", "");
```

Please notice that this code works if `$(".item.toBottom").css("display") == "block"`

**EDIT2:**

Finally solved it. The problem was that I wasn't able to calculate `$(".item.toBottom > img").height()` since **.item.toBottom** wasn't displayed. Here's the final script:

```
  var carouselHeight = $(".carousel-inner").outerHeight();
  $(".item.toBottom").css('display','block');
  var newTop = carouselHeight - $(".item.toBottom > img").height();
  $(".item.toBottom").css('display','');
  if(newTop < 0)
    $(".item.toBottom > img").css("top", newTop);
  else
    $(".item.toBottom > img").css("top", '');
```

Special thanks to @Zorken17 for the idea.

Comment: Show us your javascript

Comment: @2pha I'm adding it in the original post

Comment: What is inside .toBottom? Maybe show that code too

Comment: Use `$(".item.toBottom").show()` and `$(".item.toBottom").hide()` instead of the css property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not calculate a height if somthin is not showing, becouse the height will be 0.

You can try to wait for class .activ and then calculate.

```
if( $('.item.toBottom').hasClass('active')) {
    var carouselHeight = $(".carousel-inner").outerHeight();
    var newTop = carouselHeight - $(".item.toBottom > img").height();
    if(newTop < 0) {
        $(".item.toBottom > img").css("top", newTop);
    } else {
        $(".item.toBottom > img").css("top", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution I approched is slightly different, but the idea is yours. I'm adding it in the original post.